# Advice on Integration Flow Design

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am planning to implement an integration flow as below:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(httpInboundGateway)
    .transform(transformer-rest-api-1)
    .transform(transformer-rest-api-2)
    .handle(jdbc-outbound)
    .handle(http-outbound-gateway-1)
    .get();
```

The requirements that I want to fulfill are:

1. to make this run in parallel threads as much as possible
2. persist message at every end-point
3. make very endpoint as rest-api (to make the flow scalable)

Does it make any sense to make the flow reactive? If so how to go about it? How do I log at every step? (Does wiretap help?), and Finally, can you please provide a concrete example that of a simple implementation for above in java dsl?

Answer (score 0):

1. To make it parallel you need to consider to use an `ExecutorChannel` in between endpoints:

   ```
   IntegrationFlows.from(httpInboundGateway)
      .channel(c -> c.executor(myTaskExecutor()))
      .transform(transformer-rest-api-1)
   ```

and so on.

2. However since you would like to have a persistence option, you need to consider to use a `QueueChannel` with a persistent `MessageStore`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-store.
   Each endpoint then has to be supplied with the *poller* options, including a `tasExecutor` for parallel processing:

   ```
   .channel(c -> c.queue(jdbcMessageStore(), "queue1Channel"))
          .transform(transformer-rest-api-1, 
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(100).taskExecutor(myTaskExecutor())))
   ```
3. To make endpoints as REST API you just need to use `Http.outboundGateway()`.
   Or for reactive variant - `WebFlux.outboundGateway()` in the `.handle()` instead of `transform()`. Or just go ahead in the existing `.handle(http-outbound-gateway-1)` in your flow
4. To make flow reactive you need to use a `.channel(c -> c.flux()))`, but you'l lose a persistence on the matter.
5. To log each step, there is a `.log()` operator to be placed in between endpoints.
6. Your requirements are not clear to share some sample...